# VBA Excel DataBar not with positive and negative numbers, two colors, I need minimum negative filled completely

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a column in Excel containing positive and negative numbers and I make a data bar. I would like if lets say I have 55, 24, 0, -10 and -45 the 55 to be filled completely with green bar maximum span and -45 the same but red. This is the VBA code that I have so far:

This is visualisation wath I want to achieve:

DataBar

```
||||||||||||    (green) 12
||||||          (green) 6
||||||||||      (red)   -10
||||||||||||||  (red)   -14
```

and so on...

```
Function UpdateAmountBars(rng As Range)
    Dim min As Double, max As Double
    Let min = Application.min(rng)
    Let max = Application.max(rng)

    rng.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.count).ShowValue = True
    rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
    With rng.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax
    End With

    With rng.FormatConditions(1).BarColor
        .Color = RGB(100, 255, 100)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    rng.FormatConditions(1).BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
    rng.FormatConditions(1).Direction = xlContext
    rng.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    rng.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone

    With rng.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.Color
        .Color = RGB(255, 100, 100)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Function
```

and this is the result of the code:

[image: VBA DataBAR positive negative]

Update: I have some progress, now the databars look good but still I don't want the cells to be divided

```
Function UpdateAmountBars(rng As Range)
    Dim min As Double, max As Double, databar As databar
    Let min = Application.min(rng)
    Let max = Application.max(rng)

    Set databar = rng.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    databar.AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
    rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.count).ShowValue = True
    rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
    With rng.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin, newvalue:=min
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax, newvalue:=max
    End With

    With rng.FormatConditions(1).BarColor
        .Color = RGB(100, 255, 100)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    rng.FormatConditions(1).BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
    rng.FormatConditions(1).Direction = xlContext
    rng.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    rng.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone

    With rng.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.Color
        .Color = RGB(255, 100, 100)
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Function
```

this is the update result:

[image: VBA Data bar axisPosition]

Answer (score 0):

Add and try following code.

```
.FormatConditions(1).AxisPosition = None
```

Use the above code somewhere here in your code.

```
rng.FormatConditions(1).BarFillType = xlDataBarFillGradient
rng.FormatConditions(1).Direction = xlContext
rng.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
rng.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
```

Comment: I understand, you can not do what you expected using one conditional format. You need Two separate conditional formatting for the same range to evaluate positive and negative numbers separately. You may need different approach in codes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with my data bars. The bars are largest for negative values closest to 0 and the bars become smaller the larger the negative number is, which is the opposite of what I want to achieve.

Comment: The file which I am working on is for personal use and I havent finished it yet. As soon as I make the data bars working as expected I will share the code.